# React and Redux not rendering view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

so I am developing a small book keeping application in React+Redux. But, for some reason the view will not render, and I don't know why. The code does not throw up an error either.

Here is the structure of my app.

```
src
----actions
----components
             ----App.js
----containers
             ----bookList.js
----reducers
             ----book.js
             ----index.js
--index.js
```

Here are the individual files

index.js/src

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.js';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index.js';

let store = createStore(rootReducer);


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

/components/App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import bookList from '../containers/bookList.js';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <bookList />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

/containers/bookList.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class bookList extends Component {
    renderList() {
        return this.props.books.map(book => {
            return <li key={book.title}>{book.title}</li>
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul className='list-group col-sm-4'>
                {this.renderList()}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        books: state.books
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(bookList);
```

/reducers/index.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import books from './books.js';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    books: books
});

export default rootReducer;
```

/reducers/book.js

```
const books = () => {
    return [
        {title: 'JavaScript'}, 
        {title: 'Harry Potter'}, 
        {title: 'Some Random Title'}
    ]
}

export default books;
```

Like I mentioned at the beginning, absolutely no errors being thrown up, and any console.log statements I attempt to execute in the bookList.js file, don't show up.

Its like that file is not being read by the Babel compiler.

However, when I log the bookList function I import from bookList.js into App.js, it prints out a connect function. So, that file is clearly being imported.

Comment: Define "will not render". Are there elements on the page? Or do you mean the store is not being passed to the elements?

Comment: @shennan - It seems like the store is not being passed down to the elements. So the mapStateToProps functions gets the state object and returns the list of books props to the bookList container. However, that doesn't seem to happen, and if console.log(state) from inside mapStateToProps, I don't get any output.

Comment: @ZaidHumayun what is a result when you put console.log(this.props.books) in renderList before return statement?

Comment: @Grajek - Nothing prints out in that case.

Comment: And you have an `HTML` element with the `id` of ***"root"** defined in your `HTML`?

Comment: @Pineda - Yes. If I try to render a random Hello World text, it shows up fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out this: [User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

In case the link become invalid:

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like  or  and results in a string `'div'` or `'span'` passed to `React.createElement`. Types that start with a capital letter like  compile to `React.createElement(Foo)` and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.
>   We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this answer. This provides a more detailed explanation to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have an answer for you guys, and I think it is absolutely going to blow your mind just like it did mine.

So get this, apparently all I needed to do was change 'bookList' to 'BookList' in any occurrence of the word in the App.js file and the bookList.js file.

I have no idea why it works that way. If somebody could explain that, I would be very thankful. Because this is the first time I've come across code failing because of a difference in naming syntax.